# How do I resize a video layer (not the compossition) in After Effects?

Tags: after-effects

I created a footage of 1920x1080p, then I added a video of 1280x720p in a layer, now I would like to resize the video of this layer to fit the size of my compossition. Is this possible to do without using an external program to reconvert the original video at the desired size?.

Please, take into account in your explanations that I'm very novice using AE, I don't have more than 2 days using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you meant the composition is 1920x1080, and you wish to resize a layer to match the composition size, do one of the following:

Right-click on the layer name. In the menu that comes up, click on Transform --> Fit to comp.

Another method is, in the controls for Scale, under the Transform drilldown, right-click on one of the values. Click on `Edit Value`.  Change units to `% of composition`. Alter the value of the larger dimension, out of Width and Height, to 100%.

Comment: Thankyou. You mentioned two different ways to acchieve it, I just have one little question about it, is there a quality loss difference between those two ways?.

Comment: No difference .

Answer (score 0):

And because there's always  <del>two</del>  another way of doing things in After Effects:

- hit <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>alt/option</kbd><kbd>ctrl/⌘</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> to Scale and reposition selected layers to fit composition width, preserving image aspect ratio for each layer
- hit <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>alt/option</kbd><kbd>ctrl/⌘</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> to Scale and reposition selected layers to fit composition height, preserving image aspect ratio for each layer.

If the layer is the same aspect ratio as the comp both will have the same effect. Note that this will also centre the layer to the comp.

[Keyboard shortcuts](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/keyboard-shortcuts-reference.html) are the key to working efficiently in AE. Even though that's a complicated chord it's hella useful.